# A simple lover's riddle

Tags: riddle

> I share not quite the name of a british lover of many
>
> And when I close my eyes, I see a queen in front of me
>
> Know that I am all blackness without a french woman
>
> Who am I ? And don't mistake me for my loved one

Hint 1

> *Two of these lines are playing with the word, but maybe is it a little far fetched ?*

Hint 2

> The lover of many is also killer of many
>  The queen is really small
>  Without a french woman, I'm also without wings (still french)
>  Don't mistake me for my loved one, because so much people do

Comment: It's been 10 days now, so a hint has been added

Comment: Another (large) hint !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is:

> **Link**

---

*I share not quite the name of a british lover of many*

> James Bond is a well known British womanizer who kills in the line of duty; his surname '**Bond**' is synonymous with the verb 'link' (thanks to [SuperWild1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58252/a-simple-lovers-riddle/59080?noredirect=1#comment180934_59080)).

*And when I close my eyes, I see a queen in front of me*

> With a queen `B` (thanks to the hint & [NL628](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/59045/5208)) in front, you **blink**

*Know that I am all blackness without a french woman*

> She/her in french is *elle*, and wings (from the hint) is *ailes*, both pronounced `L`, leaving black **ink**

*Who am I ? And don't mistake me for my loved one*

> A reference to Link, the protagonist of [The Legend of Zelda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda) video games, who people often mistakenly believe is the titular Zelda (the sometimes love interest).

Comment: yayyyyy :))))))

Comment: You got it ! Only the first clue is wrong, think of a british fictionnal character ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul - I'm not British, and no characters jump to mind that have a link-like name... Certainly not one that both loves and kills many. Feel free to edit in that part of the answer so that it's complete.

Comment: Well, no need to be british to know him, and it's *not quite the name* (still, there's a relation). Let's see if someone can find it ;)

Comment: Suggested edit for the remaining hint.

Comment: I bloody knew it.. Just based off of the last sentence. Anyway, nice work!

Comment: Wow, I was totally searching in the wrong direction, I thought blackness without a french woman was backness, and this had to do with phonetics!

Comment: Good teamwork, all clues are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> bee? The queen in the riddle is the queen bee? Black and yellow bee? No wings? These are all just wild guesses :P

Comment: -1? Is this not correct?

Comment: Being incorrect should not be the reason for -1 (and I am not the downvoter).

Comment: That is not the answer, but you got part of a hint, better than nothing! :)